# XML related question

Tags: xml

Can anyone tell me how to send carriage return(`\r`),`\f`,`\n` in xml? And also how to send hex ascii code in xml for `\r`,`\n`,`\f` so that after parsing the xml, the correct action should performed.

e.g,
Request payload in soapui=> `<sms:message><![CDATA[&0x0C]]></sms:message>`

hex ascii code for `\r` => `0x0C`

after parsing,it should perform the functionality of `\r`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the CDATA for this purpose.

Example:

```
<node>
    <value><![CDATA[\n]]></value>
    <value><![CDATA[\r]]></value>
</node>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to encode any ASCII character by using "%" followed by the 2-hex-digit code of the ASCII code. For example %22 encodes a quote sign (") while a %2C encodes a comma and a %3F encodes a question mark. So, \r should be encoded by %0C, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using XML entities:

- `\f` is `&#000C;`
- `\r` is `&#000D;`
- `\n` is `&#000A;`

Entities might preserve the meaning of the control characters they represent, depending on how you process them on the client side.

That said, I don't think the form feed character (`\f`) still means anything on modern systems.